# Socrata API change from 1.0 to 2.0

Tags: socrata

After Socrata updated its API from version 1.0 to 2.0, I am not able to POST requests. I changed the URL format that is mentioned on the dev.socrata.com. I can get and see the data through a web browser but I can't through my application. Is there anything else I need to change in my POST requests for SODA API 2.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With SODA 2.0, there's no longer a need to POST to perform a query. All queries are now performed through HTTP GET requests.

Here's a quick getting started document that may help:

http://beta.dev.socrata.com/consumers/getting-started/